# Get all parent records from a collection of children

Tags: laravel

I have run into this a few times and never know the proper way of getting the correct collection. Lets say a user has

1. Replies
2. Threads

I want to get all the `Threads` a user has a `reply` on. The DB looks like

Replies

```
ID  |  thread_id  |  user_id  |  body
```

Threads

```
ID  |  user_id  |  channel_id  |  title  |  body
```

I know I could do `$user->replies` then loop through them all and retrieve the `$reply->thread` but that feels incorrect. I have seen the `hasManyTrough` but that doesn't seem right either, or I just don't understand it. Seems like this would be a common occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your relationships look like this:

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function threads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Thread::class); 
    }
}

class Thread extends Model 
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class); 
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class); 
    }
}

class Reply extends Model 
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class); 
    }

    public function thread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class); 
    }
}
```

You could add a `whereHas()` clause which would look like this:

```
$user = auth()->user();

Thread::with('user')
    ->whereHas('replies', function($query) use($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id); 
    })
    ->get();
```

The above would fetch all threads which has at least one reply that belongs to the user specified.

Comment: Thanks. I had to alter it a little. The above only gets the ones where a the user replied to and created

```Thread::whereHas('replies', function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
            })
            ->get()```